# TeamCity create arbitrary directory structure on agent

Tags: teamcity, directory-structure, agent, integration-testing

TeamCity on Windows Server + Agents

My integration-tests expect a certain directory-structure to be present, for example :

```
c:\foo\bar
```

TeamCity runs integration-tests on the agent. Therefore prior to running the tests, I need to ensure this is present on the agent.

Can this be accomplished via TC build configs ?  Or do I need to write a script ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you checkout code from a vcs(Git,svn) into teamcity . In case you are using VCS checkout , you can checkout code to a custom directory on the agent

In case you don't have a VCS checkout, you can add a script to create the directory structure you need as the first build step

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (as it was stated in previous answer) but I'd say it's not a good approach.

Why expect a directory structure and not to create it by test itself in case it's not present? In this case nobody has to care about this structure, you can change it internally and noone needs to adjust settings.

It should be rather easy to create a structure in e.g. @BeforeClass annotated method. And it can be dropped once tests are done.

Comment: I'm not familiar with @BeforeClass - could you explain more ?

Comment: It's a JUnit's annotation to instruct framework to run a method only once, before all test methods in the class. See more here: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html    I'm not sure what language/test framework you use but I guess most of them should have similar feature.

Comment: including code within the tests to create a dir-structure on the agent depends on the app tests project context having sufficient permissions to create dirs on the agent - but is this necessarily true ?  whereas the TeamCity config account will always have necessary permissions